# How do I retrieve the whole word ending at specific index in JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I know the end offset of a word , how can I get this word length (or find the index of the last space character before this word)

In the example below, I know the offset is 11 which is "k" but I want to get whole word "Back" or till the space.

```js
 var offset = 11;
 var myString = 'Welcome Back Here'; 
 console.log(myString.charAt(offset));
```

Comment: var myString = 'Welcome Back Here';    
 console.log(myString.split(' ')[1]);

Comment: Do you know exactly which word you have to get? I mean it is not dynamically changing right?

Comment: console.log(myString.splice(0,offset + 1);

Comment: `myString.match(/(B|b)(ack)+/g)[0]` try with regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this

```js
var offset = 11;
var myString = 'Welcome Back Here'; 
var idx = 0;

// Iterate backword and check for space
for (var i = offset; i >= 0; i--) {
  if (myString.charCodeAt(i) == 32) {
    idx = i + 1;
    break;
  }
}

var result = myString.slice(idx, offset+1);
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 4):

Hope this is what you are looking for.

```js
    var myString  = "Welcome Back Here";
    var offset = 11;

    function GetWordByPosition(str, position) {
        return str.substr(0, position).replace(/^.+ /g, "") + 
               str.substr(position).replace(/ .+$/g, "");
    }

    console.log(GetWordByPosition(myString , offset));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve it like this:

```
myString.substr(0, offset+1).split(' ').reverse()[0]
```

1. substring - `"Welcome Back"`
2. split on space - `["Welcome", "Back"]`
3. reverse - `["Back", "Welcome"]`
4. take first - `"Back"`

Comment: While the code is compact and correct, please, do keep in mind that it is inneficient, as it is reversing an entire array just to pick what would have been the last element; this may or may not be relevant, depending on usage and array size.

Comment: @Haroldo_OK have you measured `reverse`? speaking about performance without a benchmark is a bit meaningless IMHO.  Anyway the OP said nothing about perf.